# Tekkit factory line, avoiding item surplus?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I am trying to create a fully automated HV solar panel factory in tekkit, but I have a problem.

The parts I need for various other parts and machines are all produced at different speeds, and some of them do not have an EMC, meaning that I cannot just chuck all the surplus items into an energy condenser to get rid of them.

How can I deal with this problem? For instance, one of the machines require 2 electric circuits, some redstone, and other parts. The redstone slots are at 64 all the time, while the circuit slots in the automatic crafting table are at 1-2, meaning I over-produce redstone for this particular part of the factory.

Redstone is easy to deal with, but I also have this problem with other parts.

I notice that the energy condensers that produce the raw materials (through energy collectors) just fill up and stay full, is there a way to set up retrievers or what not to pull in what is needed instead of pumping them out continously from the energy condensers?

Meaning, when the crafting table is ready to accept redstone, it will ask for it?

Is this possible?

Comment: Most Minecraft questions tagged with SMP are also tagged with [minecraft].  Also, if the only reason you included the SMP tag is because Tekkit runs on Bukkit, then I'd suggest removing it.

Comment: This is possible. However, I would assume you are using RedPower2 pneumatic tubes and the Automatic Crafting Table Mk II? If you're using something else, there will be different answers.

Comment: Let me clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that RedPower pneumatic tubes will only send items if the source is open, so you can save yourself from overflow with those. Otherwise, for the items with an EMC, condensers are great for collection. For the other items, you could use obsidian pipes leading up to some recyclers, and put the product of that into your mass fabricators (assuming you're using them). You could also just have some obsidian pipes leading to a bunch of chests, and you can go through later and sort out what you need and don't need, or you could have machines do it. In a pinch, if you just want to get rid of waste to prevent lag, lava always works.